# What should I do when grub command-line shows up after trying to install ubuntu from usb drive?

Tags: server, grub2, usb

I'm trying to install Ubuntu Server 18.04 LTS on a new server computer.
I used *rufus* to create a usb drive for booting. Then grub commandline showed up, and when I enter “boot”, error shows up saying you need to load the kernel first.
What is wrong and what should I do to install ubuntu from the usb drive? Please help!!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to select right boot device in the BIOS of your new server computer. To tell you exactly what to do we need more information on your computer's BIOS.

But the simplest way is just to try all alternative boot options offering by your computer's BIOS one by one. If no success then change boot type from UEFI to Legacy or vise versa in computer's BIOS and try all options again. This is 'solution in the dark' so use it or provide more information on BIOS boot options.

Comment: Thanks, I solved it, I think it was the problem with the boot device set-up.

Answer (score 0):

That was the issue that I encountered.  Installed Ubuntu 20.04 from usb; set up legacy boot loader, but bios was selecting UEFI.  Visit the bios and select legacy devices.  Each device in boot list should be labeled.